# Indexing documents in Solr

Tags: batch-file, indexing, solr

I have a question about indexing documents in Solr.

I have a directory named "Doc" in this directory I have directories named "D_number" and in these directories I have documents named "D_number.doc" or "Dm_number.doc" I want only index D_number and not Dm_number, I tried this path : `C:\Documents\Doc\D_*\D_*` but it doesn't work I have this error 'No files or directories matching'

Comment: Which command are you using? The multi-level path wildcards depend on exactly how you're indexing - are you using the regular command prompt (`cmd.exe`) under Windows as well?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes I use cmd.exe with this commande line : `java -classpath C:\solr-7.3.1\dist\solr-core-7.3.1.jar  -Dauto=yes -Dc=2juil -Ddata=files -Drecursive=no org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool C:\Documents\Doc\D_*\D_*`

Comment: Rather than putting the command in comments where it's hard to read it would be better to edit the the question to add the new information there

Comment: The simple post tool is... well... simple :). Your question isn't really about solr, it's about windows command line or bat files. The post tool will consume whatever files it gets as arguments. Your problem is very likely to be that your command doesn't resolve to any files. (nothing to do with solr there).  I am not a very good windows hacker though, so I'll let someone else help you with the windows foo. It also prints a lot of nice info if you pass a `--help` argument to it.

Comment: You will need to use PowerShell or find the files and create script or do a shell script with a loop and inner posttool command. Either way, it is not a Solr issue.